# Allow internet access to public subnet

Tags: ipv4

I'm running ESXi and received a public subnet from Hertzner.de . I've setup everything by using a 'router'-vm and different client-vm's. These client VM's can access the internet through the router-vm without a problem. But how can I enable direct access to the individual VM's by their public IP's? My subnet details:

```
Subnet:    144.76.205.192 /29
Mask:    255.255.255.248
Broadcast:    144.76.205.199
```

My router VM is running on 144.76.205.193 and one of my clients on 144.76.205.194.

So how can I access them with their (public) subnet-IP's?

Comment: My iptavbles:

    # /sbin/iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
    # /sbin/iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o eth1 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
    # /sbin/iptables -A FORWARD -i eth1 -o eth0 -j ACCEPT

Comment: I solved my own question, they didn't route the subnet to my router-vm DHCP-IP, but to my main ESXI host IP. THey changed it and it now works perfectly.

Comment: Instead of commenting, you should answer your question and even accept it!